# Why would a JUnit Test fail between 12 - 1pm during Jenkins deployment?

Tags: java, postgresql, jenkins, junit

I have a JUnit test that looks for a user that hasn't changed their password in the past 355 days. In the test, I save a user with their last password update date to the system's date/time - 355 days. Then I run the function that should pick up that user for additional processing.

The test passes locally, both when the test is run on its own AND when the entire test suite is run. However, for some reason, the test fails between 12 - 1pm when deploying our code in Jenkins. It's not a consistent failure, either. Sometimes, simply running the deployment again with no changes allows the test to succeed. What could be causing this issue?

For reference, the test looks like:

```
@Test
   public void passwordExpiryTest() {
    Timestamp currentTimeMinus355Days = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30672000000L);
    createUser("expiringUser", currentTimeMinus355Days);
    createUser("recentUser", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 864000000L));
    List<User> passwordExpiringUsers = userDao.getUsersWithPasswordExpiringInTenDays();
    Assert.assertEquals(1, passwordExpiringUsers.size());
}
```

And userDao.getUsersWithPasswordExpiringInTenDays is a SQL query (into a Postgres table):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_password_update IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(epoch FROM (NOW() - last_password_update))/86400 >= 355 AND EXTRACT(epoch FROM (NOW() - last_password_update))/86400 <= 356")
```

Comment: i would change the test to call System.currentTimeMillis only once. stash it in a local variable, and use the variable contents instead. calling it two times is asking for trouble.

Comment: Perhaps that's when Jenkins takes his lunch break?  :-)

Comment: Unrelated, but `EXTRACT(epoch FROM (NOW() - last_password_update))/86400 >= 355` can be made more readable by using `last_password_update >= now() - interval '355 day'`

Comment: I originally used interval and it failed because what is a "day" to Postgres? Therefore, I changed it to use milliseconds/epoch time so everything is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate the logic in `userDao.getUsersWithPasswordExpiringInTenDays()`.  The concept of a "day" depends on an interpretation - is it 24 hours, or the next day number (e.g. 11 vs 12 of April?)?  And is there an impact of time zones?  e.g. are you testing in India, but the server lives in the US (12 hours time difference?)

Comment: I added the getUsersWithPasswordExpiringInTenDays for visibility. I'm using epoch time everywhere.